# Laravel required if validation issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Laravel required if validation issue

**Blade:**

```
        {{ Form::open(['route' => ['updateEmailSettings']]) }}   
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ Form::label('driver','Mail Driver',['class' => 'col-md-3 col-form-label required']) }}
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {{ Form::select('driver',$drivers, null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select']) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Mandrill</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            {{ Form::label('mailgun_secret','Secret',['class' => 'col-md-3 col-form-label']) }}
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {{ Form::text('mailgun["secret"]',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'mailgun_secret']) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-9 ml-md-auto">
                {{ Form::button('<i class="far fa-save"></i> Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary mr-3','type'=>'submit']) }}
                 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('emailSettings') }}"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

**Form Request:**

```
    return [
        'driver' => 'required',
        'mailgun.*.domain' => 'required_if:driver,mailgun'
    ];
```

Validation always fails. Please suggest me if i miss anything.

Comment: there is not field called 'mailgun' in the code?

Comment: @CarlosSalazar oops! I have updated the code even though it was not working.

Comment: i think the problem is the same, you are saying that mailgun.any.domain should be required if, but you're missing the 'domain' part, so mailgun.secret.domain does not exist so it fails for being required. try adding ['domain'] like mailgun["secret"]["domain"]

Comment: Check the network tab of your browsers developer tools to see what data is being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved myself

**Blade:** Removed double quotes inside the bracket.

```
{{ Form::text('mailgun[secret]',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'mailgun_secret']) }}
```

**Form Request:** Removed asterisk

```
'mailgun.domain' => 'required_if:driver,mailgun'
```